# Filter view using gem ransack with checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, checkbox, ransack

I should have 3 checkbox OP, SE and PM. If one or two is checked or even all three, the view will filter according to the checked values. These are `employee_type` and if I check OP, all employees that belong to OP type will show. I have this code using `gem 'ransack'` on `ruby on rails`

On my index.html.erb

```
<%= search_form_for @filter do |f| %>
    <%= f.check_box :employee_type, :value => 'OP', :id => 'checkOP' %>
    <%= f.check_box :employee_type, :value => 'SE', :id => 'checkSE' %>
    <%= f.check_box :employee_type, :value => 'PM', :id => 'checkPM' %>
    <%= f.submit 'Filter' %>
<% end %>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#checkOP').on('change', function() {
          var val = this.checked ? this.value : '';
          $('#index').html(val);
      });
      $('#checkSE').on('change', function() {
          var val = this.checked ? this.value : '';
          $('#index').html(val);
      });
      $('#checkPM').on('change', function() {
          var val = this.checked ? this.value : '';
          $('#index').html(val);
      });
  </script>
```

On my employees_controller

```
  def index
    @filter = Employee.search(params[:q])
    @employees = @filter.result
  end
```

There shouldn't be a button since it should have filtered the moment the checkbox is checked or unchecked but I use button just to test since there's something wrong with my code that won't auto-detect if the checkbox is checked or not.

There seems to have no solution in the internet or I just couldn't find the right words to search. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't actually do anything but fill `#index` with the value of the checkbox.  You should ensure the content area (which wasn't provided in your question) actually has an ID of `#index` (and I would suggest something less generic).  Ransack is a layer of helper tools to aid in searching.  Your javascript assumes it returns dynamic content (i.e. via Ajax), which it doesn't natively.  Your controller may implement a proper JS response type or a different action provides just the HTML content, but that is not specified in your text above.

You need to either:

1. submit the form from your javascript with something like

   ```
   $(this).parent('form').submit();
   ```

   which will submit the form and refresh the page, or
2. you need to integrate Ajax behavior into the form. This will make the form dynamic (i.e. only some page content is changed without need for a full page refresh).  When the `change` event is fired, your event needs to submit the form to a Rails action (whether index, search, whatever), and return only the content that would go in `#index`.  This can be done in many ways - either its own unique action (maybe a `search` endpoint) returning just the HTML to render without a layout, or using a `js.erb` template and proper `respond_to` in the controller to only render out the partial filling `#index` with the proper content.

If you're not familiar with Ajax (which it doesn't seem like you are, based on your provided Javascript), I would recommend a full page reload if you need to get something out quickly, and I would encourage you to look into the subject.  There's too much ground to cover in a simple stack overflow response.

A form submit would be the easiest method to achieve what you want, and it can be done by simplifying your Javascript very easily (and you should be using assets, not inline JS, if you're using Rails):

```
# index.html.erb
# give the ID a better, and more specific name:
<%= search_form_for @filter, html: { id: 'controller-action-index' } do
  ... maintain initial content
<% end %>

// in a JS file in app/assets/javascripts that is required in your application.js file
$(function() { // ensure jQuery has loaded
  // replace the ID below with whatever you use on the form above
  $('form#controller-action-index input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function (event) {
    $(this).parent('form').submit();
  });
}
```

However, that said, I would encourage you, with multiple options, and without using Ajax, to add a button, and forget about Javascript altogether.  If someone changes two options, that means they have to sit through two page refreshes, instead of simply clicking two checkboxes and clicking submit.